# How to display the image from assets folder in android?

Tags: android

I have kept my **images in assets folder** and tried to display them. I tried in many ways but still I am unable to display the image. In logcat it is not displaying any error.

Please help me regarding this..........

```
AssetManager mngr = mContext.getResources().getAssets();
        is = mngr.open("test3.png");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(pictures_directory);

        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `AssetManager` to get the InputStream using its `open()` method and then use `decodeStream()` method of `BitmapFactory` to get the Bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't right here, what error are you getting? Because the error in you question wouldn't come up from that code below... if anything it would say "Unable to open content: file:///testing/test3.png."

It sound like your images are stored in the wrong place and that is why it's saying it can't find them.

Comment: I created the images in assets folder and gave that path. Can you please tell me how to set the path for that image?

Comment: if they are in the assets folder then you are doing it right, as I said your error from the above code doesnt match up. Have you changed the code?