# Load an image from the current directory

Tags: android

**EDIT: I solved it following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151102/how-to-display-the-image-from-assets-folder-in-android?lq=1).**

In my application called "Flags" I have an image titled "Afghanistan.png" as you can see:

[image: here].

This is how I'm trying to access it:

```
Bitmap AfghanistanFlag = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/Afghanistan.png");
```

Put this just returns an error:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.nwh.flags/Afghanistan.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What do I need to do to open images in the current directory like you see in the first picture?

**EDIT: I solved it following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151102/how-to-display-the-image-from-assets-folder-in-android?lq=1).**

Comment: Why do not save your images in drawable / asset directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep all the images in asset folder of the code. And fetch them using AssetManager.
Here is a sample [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html)