# How to open an image that is stored in a folder under Assets in android

Tags: android, bitmap, assets

I have created an assets folder directory under App with Build, Libs, and Src in android studio, I have placed folders in it with images in each respectively. I have an issue that I cannot find the file in with that filename or path but I know its correct, please tell me what to do here as I am stumped. The file is in this directory assets/profileicon/26.png and the number is determined by the profileIconTag (in this case its 26) now am I doing the right path name for the .open()?

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open("/profileicon/" + profileIconTag + ".png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

    profileIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the assets folder is in the correct path.

```
InputStream bitmap=null;
try {
    bitmap=getAssets().open(profileIconTag +".png");
    Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
    profileIcon.setImageBitmap(bit);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   try{
    if(bitmap!=null)
    bitmap.close();
   }catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Comment: So I don't need to include the path for the image?

Comment: There is an error in your code, you need a try and catch around your if(bitmap!=null)bitmap.close(); and this does not work for me.

Comment: okay, with the information I have given in my original post, how would I put the path name in the .open(), as I said my path for the image would be assets/profileicon/image.png

Comment: Remove the first slash.

Comment: i guess you are passing the path wrong, try as @greenapps mentioned

Comment: @greenapps  I just tried this, .open("profileicon/" + profileIconTag + ".png"); this doesnt work, is my assets in the right place? I will post a picture

Comment: I cant post because I need a rep of 10

Comment: I got it working! I just had my assets folder in the wrong place :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AssetManager` to get the `InputStream` using its `open()` method and then use `decodeStream()` method of BitmapFactory to get the Bitmap. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151102/how-to-display-the-image-from-assets-folder-in-android).

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```